# Подтверждение почты FireBase

Tags: android, firebase, email, аутентификация

Доброго времени суток.

В чем заключается смысл подтверждения почты пользователей на FireBase?
Просто сейчас нет возможности протестировать, может быть, при неподтвержденной почте нельзя записывать в БД, если там установлено правило записи только для вошедших пользователей?

Или есть метод для проверки подтвержденной почты? Например, записывать в БД, только если пользователь подтвердил свою почту и т.д.

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для првоерки подтверждения почты используется метод *FirebaseUser.isEmailVerified()*

Пример кода:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified() == false
```

Причемание: Если пользователь подтвердил почту в тот момент, когда он был залогинен, то ему необходимо будет перезайти в свой аккаунт, чтобы метод *isEmailVerified()* возвращал *true*

[Источник](http://garmax.co/blog/firebase)